# My location application not working

Tags: java-me

I created an application in j2me to get the current location of a device and I sent it to a nokia phone whenever I launch it, instead of showing the current longitude and latitude of the device it will open a bluetooth connection. Please help me with that what went wrong?

Comment: **First of all**, how are we supposed to have any idea without seeing the code in question?  **Second of all**, you've had two heavily-downvoted, closed questions.  You need to *seriously* re-read the Help and FAQ sections and find out how to ask questions properly, otherwise you run the risk of an automated quesiton ban for low-quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check what location methods you have enabled in phone's settings (in some Nokia phones, there is *settings->application settings->location->my position->methods* or something like that) to see if you have other methods except Bluetooth GPS enabled (Integrated GPS, WiFi, Network, ...). 
But, I believe, that by default it would use internal GPS... does your Nokia really have it?